# No $C^1$ homeomorphism between Euclidean spaces

Tags: general-topology

Is there a somehow elementary proof to show that there's no $C^1$ homeomorphism between $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ where $m\neq n$?

Comment: Yes for $C^1$ diffeomorphisms. But I know of no proof for $C^1$ homeomorphisms except for proofs that work for general homeomorphisms.

Comment: You are making me wonder, though: If $M,N$ are two $C^1$-manifolds, and if there exists a $C^1$-homeomorphism from $M$ to $N$, does there exist a $C^1$-diffeomorphism $f : M \to N$? And is there a "somehow elementary proof" of existence of $f$?